# How to black-box test transaction atomicity?

Tags: database, testing, transaction

Suppose we need to ensure that a sequence of database operations - currently implemented as A followed by B followed by C - executes either all together, or not at all. We can achieve this using a database transaction - but how can we write an automated test to verify that this atomicity property is satisfied, which is not brittle?

We can fairly easily write a white-box test for this: given that we know that A is executed first, then B, then C, we can write a test which injects a fake C and makes the fake C throw a runtime exception instead of issuing a database update query, to simulate a system crash. Then we catch that exception in the test, and assert that nothing in the database has changed since the test began running.

However, if a developer later comes along and rewrites the implementation to call C first, our test will become invalid - it will only test that "if nothing happens, then nothing happens" or in other words "if the system crashes immediately, then nothing will be written to the database". Not a very useful test, and not testing what we want to test! This is because it's a white-box test which is predicated on an assumption about the order of operations inside the implementation - namely, that C is executed last (or at least, not first).

Is it possible to avoid the test turning into a bogus test in this way if the order of database operations in the implementation is changed?

Comment: Is your test subject the DB software? No rewrite to the DB implementation ought to change the order of operations in a transaction, and this test can guard that by having op C depend on data inserted by ops A and B. If not, I can't guess what the test subject is.

Comment: I agree with @Jerry101: testing the correctness of the code in your DB is out of scope for an application using it. And also for tests in the DB codebase this doesn't make much sense. The level of reliability that is needed from a database is on the "thourough, mathematical proof" level, not the "throw some tests at it and reduce the risk of a bug to .x%" level.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what is being tested. If you're testing whether the transactional consistency works properly when a series of operations end with some sort of crash, then clearly the order of operations is important - as you say, if you change the order to start with the crash, then nothing will be tested. At least one successful statement must precede the crash, within the scope of the transaction, in order to test whether the successful statement is rolled back as a result of the crash which occurs subsequently.

Comment: @Jerry101 No, to clarify, the system under test is not the DBMS. It's either the application, or a part of the application. The test might be configured to use an in-memory database for performance and robustness. Making operation C depend on data inserted by A or B would be quite complicated, and wouldn't change the fact that the test would be a white-box test which would assume certain things about the implementation, as far as I can see.

Comment: @RobinGreen if you want to do a black-box test you **are** testing the DBMS. To minimize the touch-points of your test the only sensible thing i can think of is testing whether the application does it's stuff in a transaction. Like assert that `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` are run as the first and last command to the DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

I you really want to test the details of DB operations in your code, the method is the same as always: you mock the component that *receives* the operations and assert that the received operations satisfy certain constraints.

For instance, you might assert that **all** the operations are wrapped into transaction boundaries (explicitly or implicitly). (For bonus points you could also construct an in-memory DB that throws on a specific operation, and then assert that if this happens, its entire state remains unchanged. But in my view, testing that your code does X is better done directly, i.e. by observing what it does through a collaborator that snitches on your module.)